# How to set width to Material widget on Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, widget, material-ui, flutter-layout

I've a `Material` widget to wrap a `MaterialButton` to make border radius, but I can't set the `width` attribute to it. I tried use a `SizedBox` but not works, the `Material` widget keep using all space of screen.

**Code:**

```
return new SizedBox(
              width: 40,
              child: Material(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)),
                elevation: 18.0,
                color: Color(0xFF801E48),
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, 
                child: MaterialButton(
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  height: 30.0,
                  child: new Text('Sair',
                      style:
                          new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white)),
                ),
              ),
            );
```

**Result:**

[image]

Clearly it not have 40.0 of width size.

Answer (score 7):

A better approach is using Container widget. When you need to change width, height or add padding/margin to any widget you should wrap the target widget into a container. The container widget is for this kind of job.

```
Container(
  width: myWidthValue, // Container child widget will get this width value
  height: myHeghtValue, // Container child widget will get this height value
  padding: allowPaddingToo, // padding is allowed too
  child: Material(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)),
                elevation: 18.0,
                color: Color(0xFF801E48),
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // Add This
                child: MaterialButton(
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  height: 30.0,
                  child: new Text('Sair',
                      style:
                          new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isNeedHelp = false;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved using `Padding`:

```
return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 0, 50, 0),
              child: Material(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)),
                elevation: 18.0,
                color: Color(0xFF801E48),
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // Add This
                child: MaterialButton(
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  height: 30.0,
                  child: new Text('Sair',
                      style:
                          new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isNeedHelp = false;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can set the size, padding, and margin of widgets in general. here is an example for Button:

```
   Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10), // Top Margin
          child:
            ElevatedButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(

                // Inside Padding 
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 20), 

                // Width,Height
                minimumSize: Size(300, 30), 
              ),
              child: Text('Upload Data'),
              onPressed: () {submitForm();},
            ),
        ),
```

[image]